# Error while sending image to web server, image doesn't show on server

Tags: android, http, httprequest, httpurlconnection

my code should send image with few parameters to web server with multipart request. The parameters are sent with no problems, but the image apears as empty image file and error data cames with response: {"name":"1372429494726.jpg","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":"Unable to upload photo.","size":0,"max_file_size":8}

What might be the problem? Thanks

```
public boolean sendPicture(String photoUrl, String clientId, String rep){

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        String urlServer = "http://myserver/v1/photos.json";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ;
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        try{
            File photoFile = new File(photoUrl);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(photoFile);
            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            // Send normal params.
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset), true);
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(lineEnd);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"rep\"").append(lineEnd);
            writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(lineEnd);
            writer.append(lineEnd);
            writer.append(rep).append(lineEnd).flush();

            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(lineEnd);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"clientId\"").append(lineEnd);
            writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(lineEnd);
            writer.append(lineEnd);
            writer.append(clientId).append(lineEnd).flush();

            // send image
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(lineEnd);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"; filename=\"" + photoFile.getName() + "\"").append(lineEnd);
            writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(photoFile.getName())).append(lineEnd);
            writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(lineEnd);
            writer.append(lineEnd).flush();

            InputStream input = null;
            try{
                input = new FileInputStream(photoFile);
                bytesAvailable = input.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                for(int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;){
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
            }finally{
                if(input != null) try{
                    input.close();
                }catch(IOException logOrIgnore){
                }
            }
            writer.append(lineEnd).flush();
            writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(lineEnd);

              //read response
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            InputStream errorInput = connection.getErrorStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorInput));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = r.readLine()) != null){
                total.append(line);
            }
            Log.v("error", total.toString());
            Log.v("serverResponseCode", "" + serverResponseCode);
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.v("serverResponseMessage", "" + serverResponseMessage);

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            writer.close();
            Log.v("uploaded photo", "" + photoUrl);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.d("UploadPhotoTask", ex.getMessage());
        }finally{
            if(writer != null) writer.close();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: anything useful from `Wireshark`
?

Comment: not really using it. Is it worth trying?

Comment: oh yes! i use it all the time when there is a communication with a server involved

Comment: it is like using -v flag with cURL - it will output lots of info and what it sends and receives in order to let you see all client-server interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it:

```
 public boolean sendPicture(String photoUrl, String clientId, String rep){

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = photoUrl;
        String urlServer = "http://myserver/v1/photos.json";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while(bytesRead > 0){
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"clientId\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(clientId + lineEnd);

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"rep\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(rep + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.v("serverResponseCode", "" + serverResponseCode);
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                Log.d("server", line);

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.d("UploadPhotoTask", ex.getMessage());
            return false;
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(serverResponseCode == 200) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```